# Loudspeaker transducer FCC certification?

Tags: audio, amplifier, radio, fcc

Is FCC certification necessary for speaker transducers that are sold as assembled units in their housings?
I found information on active speakers needing fcc certification, but what about passive speakers that use external amplifiers? What about UL certification?

Answer (score 1):

Since a passive speaker doesn't emit EMI by itself, I can't see how the FCC would care.  FCC rules would cover the entire system, from amp to cables to speaker, if sold as a whole system.  Since it would be unintentional radiator, certification is not mandatory, but you'd better be within the limits if they decide to look (quite unlikely) due to some incident or complaint.

There are probably a number of standards UL could certify a speaker to, like flammability and the like.  However none of that is legally required.  Some resellers won't carry products without UL or similar certification to particular standards, depending on what the product is.

Comment: Do you have a ballpark cost estimate for UL certification for simple devices like this? I read $40,000 somewhere. Does that sound correct?

Comment: @Peter: That can vary widely depending on the device and the standard(s) being tested to.  $40k sounds high for a simple passive speaker tested against existing standards.

Comment: You can also look at an ETL mark: http://www.intertek.com/marks/etl/ - They do UL equivalent testing. $40k also sounds very high to me.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please explain what youo think is incorrect.  I have re-read what I wrote and still don't see anything wrong.